# How to properly split a specific string in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, split

I have a **list** of **string** values that represents the `id.age` of some users:

```
users = ["1.20", "2.35", "3", "4", "5.", "6.30", "7."]
```

How can I properly split it to get the `id` and `age` separately?

Note that we have some data with the `age` information missing (e.g. `"3"` and `"4"`), and even worse, we have some data only with an `id` and a point (e.g. `"5."` and `"7."`).

Sure I can use the split function, for example:

```
>>> "1.2".split('.')
['1', '2']
>>> "2".split('.')
['2']
>>> "3.".split('.')
['3', '']
```

But, then I will need to check each result. Maybe, something like this:

```
res = "3.".split('.')
id = int(res[0])
if len(res) > 1:
    if res[1] != "":
        age = int(res[1])
```

Another option is to use the `rpartition` function, for example:

```
>>> "1.2".rpartition('.')
('1', '.', '2')
>>> "2".rpartition('.')
('', '', '2')
>>> "3.".rpartition('.')
('3', '.', '')
```

But I still need to check the results 'manually' and, in the second example, the value that should be the `id` is in the `age` position. (e.g. `('', '', '2')`).

Is there a built in function that I can get the result like this?

```
>>> "1.2".some_split_function('.')
('1', '.', '2')
>>> "2".some_split_function('.')
('2', None, None)
>>> "3.".some_split_function('.')
('3', '.', None)
```

So I can just call it in a loop like this:

```
for user_info in users:
    id, _, age = user_info.some_split_function('.')
    print int(id)
    if age is not None:
        print int(age)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, you just use `partition` instead of `rpartition`.

```
for user_info in users:
    id, _, age = user_info.partition('.')
    if age.isdigit():
        print int(age)
```

You'll want to change that conditional from being `None` to just checking if you've pulled out a number appropriately. This will take care of empty strings etc...

In general though, the way to avoid this problem is to not structure your data like that in the first place.

Seeing some of the other answers, no reason to do anything so complex. If you want a functional solution that maps id to age, then I would advocate for something like this:

```
>>> {id: age or None for id, _, age in [user.partition(".") for user in users]}
{'1': '20', '3': None, '2': '35', '5': None, '4': None, '7': None, '6': '30'}
```

Comment: Have you tested your code? Because I'm pretty there's no such a thing as `lpartition`.

Comment: I'm getting the following error when trying to use `lpartition`: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'lpartition'`. Just to clarify, the data is not 'correctly' structured because it is coming from a text file manually edited.

Comment: Apologies, I'm on a strange python version, just `partition`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, we split `u` only if it contains `.`, if not, `u` is the id and age is assigned `None`.

```
users = ["1.20", "2.35", "3", "4", "5.", "6.30", "7."]
data = []

for u in users:
    id, age = u.split('.') if '.' in u else [u, None]
    age = None if age == '' else age
    data.append({id: age})
```

If you want your ids to be integers, just call `int()` function on `id` like this:

```
data.append({int(id): age})
```

**Output:**

```
>>> data
[{'1': '20'}, {'2': '35'}, {'3': None}, {'4': None}, {'5': None}, {'6': '30'}, {'7': None}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ettanany, this is a great example and fits very well in my case.

Comment: @KelvinS Great! Happy to help :)

Comment: @ettanany Code is overly complex. Injecting a lot of useless logic just to compensate for the fact that you're using `split` instead of `partition`, which is a better solution. List of dicts as an output format also doesn't make a lot of sense for this problem.